# Preventing label crowding in PieChart RadialCallout and RadialCenter

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to avoid this unreadable situation with label crowding when using `PieChart`'s `RadialCallout` and `RadialCenter` methods?

```
PieChart[tabData109[[All, 2]], 
 SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 1}, 
 ChartStyle -> tabData109[[All, 1]] /. PACE["TAB_COLOR_RULES"],
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Row[{NumberForm[
        100 # /Plus @@ tabData109[[All, 2]] // N, {3, 1}], "%"}], 
     "RadialCenter"] &),
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[tabData109[[All, 1]] /. PACE["TAB_DESCRIPTION_RULES"], 
   "RadialCallout"]]
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Well maybe it's `LabelingFunction` what you are looking for.

Comment: OK now I think it might not be possible to avoid crowding near some TOO narrow sectors (eg. those percentages for the right above white sectors). So maybe you will have to put them outside, increasing radials of some labels?

Comment: It seems not so easy for me.. My basic idea is to rearrange the labels in the chart after having been generated by `PieChart`. So at least placement of each label is needed. Haven't figured out how to get them efficiently. And I have to say the underlying expression of the chart doesn't looks friendly enough..

Comment: Couldnt you just ROTATE the Lables according to the angle of their respective pie? I would love to know how to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the following thought about the question.

## Part 1

We generate some random crowded test data first:

```
data = RandomChoice[{20, 15, 8, 7, 6, 5} -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10}, 50]
```

> {1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
>   2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 
>   1, 1, 5, 4}

```
dataLength = Length[data]; 

descriptionData = (FromCharacterCode[RandomInteger[{97, 122}, 
        {RandomInteger[{4, 10}]}]] & ) /@ data
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
valueData = (NumberForm[#1, {3, 1}] & ) /@ N[(100*data)/Total[data]]; 

labelLst = MapThread[Row[{#1, ":  ", #2, "%"}] & , {descriptionData, valueData}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then draw the `PieChart` using system function:

```
chartgraph = PieChart[data,
  SectorOrigin -> {{\[Pi]/2, "Clockwise"}, 1},
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
      Framed[Style[
        labelLst[[#2[[2]]]],
        Bold, 13],
       Background -> Lighter[Purple, 0.95]],
      "RadialCallout"] &),
  ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[{White, Opacity[0.2]}],
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Part 2

Now we'll do some dirty job, modify the underlying data of `chartgraph`.

First define some functions which are not aesthetic at all, and are very likely not so general for any `PieChart`. (Their function is adjusting the radial of `"RadialCallout"` lines.)

```
Clear[extentFunc]
extentFunc[labeldata_, Radial_] :=
 ReplaceAll[labeldata,
  {{{}, {}}, {{{}, {}},
     {directive1__?(Head[#] =!= LineBox &),
      LineBox[{r0_, R0_}],
      LineBox[{R0_, endpoint_}]},
     {directive2__?(Head[#] =!= LineBox &),
      DiskBox[r0_, diskR_]},
     InsetBox[labeltext_, labPos_, labOPos_]}} :>
   With[{R = Radial/Norm[R0] R0},
    With[{v = R - R0},
     horizonLineLength = Abs[(endpoint - R0)[[1]]];
     {{{}, {}}, {{{}, {}},
       {directive1,
        LineBox[{r0, R}],
        LineBox[{R, endpoint + v}]},
       {directive2, DiskBox[r0, diskR]},
       InsetBox[labeltext, labPos + v, labOPos]}}
     ]]]

Clear[chartExtentFunc]
chartExtentFunc[chartgraph_, Radial_?NumericQ] :=
 ToExpression[ReplacePart[
   ToBoxes[chartgraph],
   {1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1} -> (
     ReplacePart[#,
        1 -> extentFunc[#[[1]], Radial]
        ] & /@
      ToBoxes[chartgraph][[1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]]
     )]]

chartExtentFunc[chartgraph_, Radial_List] :=
 ToExpression[
  With[{num = $ModuleNumber},
    StringReplace[ToString[
      ReplacePart[
       ToBoxes[chartgraph],
       {1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1} -> (
         MapThread[
          ReplacePart[#1, 1 -> extentFunc[#1[[1]], #2]] &,
          {ToBoxes[chartgraph][[1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]],
           Radial}]
         )],
      InputForm],
     "DynamicChart`click$" ~~ (a : DigitCharacter ..) ~~ 
       "$" ~~ (b : DigitCharacter ..) :>
      "DynamicChart`click$" <> a <> "$" <> ToString[num]
     ]] // ToExpression]
```

Now try them on our `chartgraph` with random radials:

```
chartExtentFunc[chartgraph,RandomReal[{2.1, 3},dataLength]]/.Thickness[a_]:>Thickness[.5 a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is of course nice to associate radials with correspond polar angles:

```
\[Theta]Set = \[Pi]/2 - (Accumulate[#] - 1/2 #) &[
data/Total[data] 2 \[Pi]] // N;

2 + If[0 <= # < \[Pi]/8 || \[Pi] - \[Pi]/8 < # < \[Pi] + \[Pi]/8 || 
  2 \[Pi] - \[Pi]/8 < # <= 2 \[Pi], 2.1 Abs[Cos[#]]^12, .3/
 Abs[Sin[#]]] & /@ (\[Pi]/2 - \[Theta]Set);

chartExtentFunc[chartgraph, %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MapIndexed[
  Piecewise[{{2.4, # == 0}, {3.4, # == 1}, {4.4, # == 2}}] &[
Mod[#2[[1]], 3]] &, (\[Pi]/2 - \[Theta]Set)];

chartExtentFunc[chartgraph, %] /. Thickness[_] :> Thickness[0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Part 3

Well the above results are not so nice. So we try to improve it by introducing an optimization function (potential function).

```
RvariableSet = Table[Symbol["R" <> ToString[i]], {i, dataLength}]

Clear[centerPos]
centerPos[k_] := 
 R[[k]] {Cos[\[Theta][[k]]], Sin[\[Theta][[k]]]} + {L, 0} + {W/2, 0}

Clear[centerPotentialFunc]
centerPotentialFunc[k_, Rmin_, Rmax_] := 
 Exp[-10 (R[[k]] - Rmin)] + Exp[10 (R[[k]] - Rmax)]

Clear[interactionPotentialFunc]
interactionPotentialFunc[i_, j_] := If[i == j, 0,
  With[{d = Sqrt[#.#]/Sqrt[W^2 + H^2] &[centerPos[i] - centerPos[j]]},
   2 Exp[-10 (d - 1.1)]
   ]]
```

(Here `W` and `H` are the max width and height of the label text box separately.)

```
potentialExpr = 
  Block[{\[Theta] = \[Theta]Set, L = horizonLineLength, W = 1.3, 
H = 0.25, R = RvariableSet},
   Sum[centerPotentialFunc[i, 2.2, 5], {i, 1, dataLength}] + 
Sum[interactionPotentialFunc[i, j], {i, 1, dataLength},
   {j, 1, dataLength}]];
```

(Here for each `i`, the upper and lower bound of `j` can be localized to neighborhood of it to reduce the size of `potentialExpr`.)

Grad of the total potential (I thinks here I "inject" `RvariableSet` in an unidiomatic way?):

```
gradExpr = Module[{CompileTemp},
   CompileTemp[RvariableSet, Evaluate[
      D[potentialExpr, #] & /@ RvariableSet
      ]] /. CompileTemp -> Compile];
```

Run the kinetics simulation for 300 steps:

```
initRSet = ConstantArray[3, dataLength];

dt = 1 10^-3;

RSetSet = NestList[Function[paras, Module[{a, v},
     v = paras[[2]];
     a = -gradExpr @@ paras[[1]];
     v = v + 1/2 dt a;
     (If[#[[1]] < 
       2.1, {2.1, -#[[2]]}, {#[[
        1]], .1 #[[2]]}] & /@ ({paras[[1]] + dt v, 
       v}\[Transpose]))\[Transpose]
     ]], {initRSet, ConstantArray[0, dataLength]}, 300];

Manipulate[
 ListPolarPlot[{\[Theta]Set, RSetSet[[k, 1]]}\[Transpose], 
  PlotStyle -> Purple, Joined -> True, 
  Epilog -> {Circle[{0, 0}, 2.1], Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}, PlotRange -> All],
 {k, 1, Length[RSetSet], 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now try the result on `chartgraph`:

```
chartExtentFunc[chartgraph, RSetSet[[-1, 1]]]/.Thickness[a_]:>Thickness[.5 a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
% /. FrameBox[expr_, opt__] :> expr /. Bold -> Plain
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it's kind of better now. (Though still not good enough..)

## Conclusion

Thus far, it seems if I choose a proper potential function, I will get a good result. But the final results are not as satisfying as I want. I think there can be more essential improvements, for efficiently and for better result.

Comment: No doubt about it, this is a very good answer. Still, I can't help thinking that, if you find yourself in such a pathological situation, it might be worth reconsidering whether a pie chart is really the best way to present the data.

Comment: @OleksandrR. yes totally agree with you about reconsidering a best way to present the data. On the other hand, I just feel fun to draw those iris like charts, they induced me and made me wondering :) Anyway, kind of sharing it for pretty generated pictures :)

Comment: Thanks for all the nice work Silvia. I've also forwarded this page to WRI's tech team for consideration.

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks. I believe they have nicer solutions. (such as the algorithm used in `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` layout for `GraphPlot`)

Answer (score 9):

For moderately crowded cases like yours there is a very simple solution. Because I do not have your data, I will use a modified example from Documentation. There is a typical problem of crowded labels in the **Image 1**. And it is fixed on the **Image 2** by using [**SectorOrigin**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SectorOrigin.html) option to adjust angular positions of labels so to distribute them properly. You basically should shift location of most dense label areas from "north" and "south" to "east" and "west".

**Image 1 - crowded labels**

[image]

**Image 2 - correction by rotation via [SectorOrigin](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SectorOrigin.html) option**

[image]

**The code**

```
Manipulate[

 elem = SortBy[
   Tally[Flatten[
     Table[ElementData[z, "DiscoveryCountries"], {z, 1, 108}]]], Last];

 Column[{

   PieChart[
    Apply[Labeled[#1, #2, "RadialCallout"] &, 
     Transpose[{N[(elem[[All, 2]]/Total[elem[[All, 2]]])], 
       elem[[All, 1]]}], 2],  
    LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
        Row[{NumberForm[100 #, 2], "%"}, "\[MediumSpace]"], 
        Tooltip] &), ChartStyle -> "LightTerrain", PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["RadialCallout", Bold, 16], ImageSize -> 320, 
    SectorOrigin -> k],

   PieChart[
    Apply[Labeled[#1, #2, "VerticalCallout"] &, 
     Transpose[{N[(elem[[All, 2]]/Total[elem[[All, 2]]])], 
       elem[[All, 1]]}], 2],  
    LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
        Row[{NumberForm[100 #, 2], "%"}, "\[MediumSpace]"], 
        Tooltip] &), ChartStyle -> "LightTerrain", PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["VerticalCallout", Bold, 16], ImageSize -> 340,
     SectorOrigin -> k]

   }]

 , {{k, 1.3, "rotate"}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 FrameMargins -> 0]
```

Comment: Rotation is indeed a good idea. But how about it's crowded everywhere?

Comment: @Silvia  Thanks! I think introducing label whiskers of alternating lengths would help a completely overcrowded labels. But this needs more work.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, +1 but even on the simple dataset shown above, no angular value of SectorOrigin can prevent all overlaps. I think a general problem with intelligent label layout is there's no easy (or any) way to retrieve text bounding boxes. Do you know of a way?

Answer (score 7):

In 11.1, `Callout` support was added to `PieChart`. This does something similar to Silvia's second example in part 2 of her [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9082/52). Using her data

```
data = RandomChoice[{20, 15, 8, 7, 6, 5} -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10}, 50];
dataLength = Length[data];
descriptionData = 
 (FromCharacterCode[RandomInteger[{97, 122}, {RandomInteger[{4, 10}]}]] &) /@ data;
valueData = (NumberForm[#1, {3, 1}] &) /@ N[(100*data)/Total[data]];
labelLst = MapThread[Row[{#1, ":  ", #2, "%"}] &, {descriptionData, valueData}];
```

it is fairly simple to set up

```
PieChart[data, SectorOrigin -> {{\[Pi]/2, "Clockwise"}, 1},
 ChartLabels -> Callout[Style[#, 14] & /@ labelLst], 
 ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[{White, Opacity[0.2]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Two things of note: 1) I had to expand the size of the image to avoid overlap, and 2) I clicked on a couple of the pie pieces to demonstrate what that looks like in this scheme.

Comment: +1 Didn't see this answer until just now. However, [it doesn't seem to work the same way in version 12.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGZRs.png)?

Comment: @Silvia I can't be held accountable for the algorithm changes between versions. :)