# How to style and position VerticalCallouts and RadialCallouts

Tags: options, labeling, charts

Here is a pie chart with a labels placed with a "VerticalCallout"

```
PieChart[Range[10],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[Range[10], "VerticalCallout", Style[#, Red, Bold, 14] &],
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

[image]

I was trying to figure out what, if any, options control the colour and thickness of the "call out" lines and disk. So

Q1. Are there built in options to change this styling?

I was able to alter the styling via a rule replacement:

```
PieChart[Range[10],
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[Range[10], "VerticalCallout", Style[#, Red, Bold, 14] &],
  SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}] /. {{x_Thickness, _GrayLevel, 
    y_Opacity, z__} :> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Red, y, 
    z}, {_GrayLevel, _Opacity, Disk[x_List, _]} :> {Red, 
    Disk[x, 0.05]}}
```

[image]

But...

Q2. Is there a way to specify the vertical positioning of the labels (for "VerticalCallout"? That is, to specify how far left and right from pie chart that they are positioned?

By default they appear to align at the "image boundary" but if I set image padding or alter the plot range the label positions don't alter.

**Edit**

ok I have figured out Q2 via rule replacements as well but would still like to know if this can be controlled via built in options.

```
PieChart[Range[10],
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   ImagePadding -> 0,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   PlotRange -> {{-4.5, 4.5}, {-4.5, 4.5}},
   ChartLabels -> 
    Placed[Range[10], "VerticalCallout", Style[#, Red, Bold, 14] &],
   SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}] /. {Text[x_, {a_, b_}, z_] :> 
    Text[x, {a*1.8, b}, z], {x_Thickness, _GrayLevel, y_Opacity, 
     z__} :> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Red, y, z}, {_GrayLevel, _Opacity,
      Disk[x_List, _]} :> {Red, Disk[x, 0.05]}} /. 
 Line[{{x_, y_}, {z_, y_}}] :> Line[{{x, y}, {z*1.8, y}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any ready options for those purposes.. Post-modifications seem to be the best we users can do. Please refer to [my answer to a relevant question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9082/17).

Comment: Some spelunking in a `Trace` of your code suggests that the settings are hardcoded. For example, the radius of the disk is set by the value of `Charting‘ChartLabelingDump‘r1$`. I tried setting this but could not find a way to change the value used. Incidentally, I found two undocumented labeling options, `"Staggered"` (same as `"RadialOuter"`) and `"CircularUniformFramed"`. Try: `PieChart[Range[10], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[Range[10], "CircularUniformFramed", 
   Style[#, Red, Bold, 14] &], SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]`

Comment: you must have extraordinary patience @Verbeia to go through the `Trace`. Looks like "Roger" was the developer based on the large number of "roger" references. :)

Comment: You've see my brute-force coding methods - :) actually it didn't take that long to isolate the `r$` thing by searching for `Callout`.

Comment: I found some other weird options like `PopoutSpacing` and `Popout->True` but I couldn't work out what they did.

Comment: I worked them out - added [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/8).